# Canonical Quantization of harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, hamiltonian

I have a system of two particles with the usual Lagrangian,

$$L=\frac12M_1{\dot{x_1}}^2+\frac12M_2{\dot{x_2}}^2-\frac12k({x_1}^2+{x_2}^2)$$

I want to find the quantum Hamiltonian of the system. I started with finding the classical Hamiltonian using,

$$H=p_1\dot{x_1}+p_2\dot{x_2}-L$$ where $p_1$ and $p_2$ are the canonical momenta. How can I find the quantum Hamiltonian of the system?

I think I have to apply the canonical commutator relationship $$[{x_i},{p_i}]=i\hbar$$

Comment: Hint: You also need the notion of "direct" product

Answer (score -1, accepted):

HINT: The conjugate variables are: $p_i = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}_i}$.
After computing H by Legendre transform you have to express the time derivatives of $x_1,x_2$ in terms of momenta $p_1,p_2$. After using definition of momentum operator you have the quantum Hamiltonian.